# Reload page in iframe using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

How can I reload an aspx page in an iframe using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#idOfIframe").attr("src",$("#idOfIframe").attr("src"));
```

Comment: hi.. thank u for Ur answer... But its not working... I want to load the aspx page on iframe, now only src is changed.. Page load does not happen.......

Comment: You want to reload same page or assign new aspx page given iframe?